# Flash video gets stuck often

Tags: 11.04, video

I use Ubuntu 11.04, the flash videos gets stuck frequently. However the audio still plays, if we scroll the window a bit then the video plays properly. Otherwise it gets stuck, this behavior is same for all video sites (Youtube, Google video etc)

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that gnash does a better job for streaming video than flash  to install gnash there isn't really any need to remove flash you can install gnash by  `sudo apt-get install gnash`  Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue with Flash on Linux in general but more specifically some browsers and certain releases of browsers perform better. Personally I had lots of issues with Google Chrome and Flash until I moved to Beta Channel.